# Java Method overloading- input parameters for method is double and double, Passed arguments are int and double

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I am new to Java and trying to learn method overriding.
When I execute the following, the output is -35. Can someone please explain this?

```
public static void f(int a, int b) {

    System.out.println(a + b);
}

public static void f(double a, double b) {

    System.out.println(a - b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 19;
    double x = 54.0;

    f(i, x); 
}
```

Output:
`-35`

Comment: Please format your question. What value do you expect and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method with `double` parameters is being called because `double` takes priority over `int`. This is because an `int` can be assigned to a `double`, but not the other way around.

For example:

```
int a = 0;
double b = 0;
b = a; // Okay
a = b; // error
```

So calling `f(int a, int b)` with a `double` and an `int` will cause an error, while calling `f(double a, double b)` will not, because the `int` will just be cast to a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Java chooses the most specific applicable type. In this case f(int,int) is not applicable.

It chooses the f(double,double) because both arguments can be converted to double but both arguments can't be converted to int without loss. If the f(double,double) did not exist the f(int,int) still couldn't be used without a cast.

More info in the specification:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2